# Multiple plugins settings of same developer into ONE settings page linked together

Tags: plugins, options, add-menu-page, add-submenu-page, page-specific-settings

Im quite new to wordpress and plugins.
I'm still a student so im still in the learning curve.

Thank you in advance for reading my question

**CONTEXT**

Each plugin is a plugin on its own but made *by the same dev* and could be used alone or together.

The plugins need **one and the same API KEY** and maybe later might need some other settings to be filled out to customize a users experience with these plugins.

In other words you could choose to just install ONE plugin and it would work perfectly fine. However if they choose to use more than one feature plugin i would like that **the settings** all come **into one settings page tab**, instead of each plugin having their own settings page and therefore having 'foo,foo,foo,foo' into the settings section.
( see images for photoshopped visualisation )

**QUESTION**

Could it be possible to combine all plugins installed their settings ( when theres more than one ) into ONE and the same settings page so a user needs to fill in the Api key once? ( And optionally have all the settings for those plugins into different tabs if there will be new customize features )

**REASON**

This way the Api key only needs to be filled out ONCE instead of (x) amount of times and theres not 8 settings pages of the same developer name into settings.

**THE IDEA**

Basically if the page is already made by another plugin of the same developer , take the main tab for example where u fill out the api key of tab 'Api key' and add a subpage of plugin with name 'foo' , 'bar', 'foobar' , ..

For visualisation you can look at the images which i photoshopped

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance!